# very slow boot time at linux - how to improve

Tags: systemd, boot

```
sudo systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 35.729s (firmware) + 5.933s (loader) + 32.920s (kernel) + 3min 18.149s (userspace) = 4min 32.732s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 46.619s in userspace
```

and

```
systemd-analyze blame
1min 41.665s sendmail.service
1min 31.112s podman-auto-update.service
1min 19.116s postgresql@10-main.service
1min 17.766s postgresql@12-main.service
1min 17.311s postgresql@13-main.service
     59.659s mpd.service
     37.709s user@1000.service
     34.906s systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
     33.412s nmbd.service
     33.152s apache2.service
     30.795s lightdm.service
     30.746s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     29.475s vmware.service
     27.070s udisks2.service
     24.988s networkd-dispatcher.service
     23.200s accounts-daemon.service
     19.811s lxc-net.service
     15.702s upower.service
     14.965s avahi-daemon.service
     14.964s NetworkManager.service
     14.573s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     14.191s polkit.service
     14.189s power-profiles-daemon.service
     14.022s switcheroo-control.service
     14.016s wpa_supplicant.service
     13.695s systemd-udev-settle.service
     13.529s systemd-logind.service
     13.513s vmware-USBArbitrator.service
     12.911s dev-sda2.device
```

system information

```
     ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.        OS: Debian 11 bullseye
    ,g$$P""       """Y$$.".      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.11.0-18-generic
   ,$$P'              `$$$.      Uptime: 18m
  ',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:    Packages: 6057
  `d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$     Shell: bash
   $$P      d$'     ,    $$P     Resolution: 1920x1080
   $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'     DE: KDE 5.80.0 / Plasma 5.21.4
   $$\;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      WM: KWin
   Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'          GTK Theme: Breeze [GTK2], Adwaita [GTK3]
   `$$b      "-.__               Icon Theme: breeze
    `Y$$                         Disk: 569G / 1.4T (44%)
     `Y$$.                       CPU: Intel Core i5-4570S @ 4x 3.6GHz [30.0°C]
       `$$b.                     GPU: NV138
         `Y$$b.                  RAM: 3043MiB / 7909MiB
            `"Y$b._
```

I have 4 hdd connected through usb hub and 2 usb hdd to usb port. all hdd externals western passport. but only on1 disk is mounted auto on boot time.

I have installed minisql (faster postgresql alternatives?) I connect my android phone to pc. i have wired internet.

a) sendmail service took almost 2 minutes - can i disable? b) psotgresql alternatives? why 3 instances? c) mpd service for music network very slow. alternatives?

so my boot time may be better by 5 minutes if fix those ones!!!

any thought?

UPDATE: after uninstalling postgresql (which may i need in future)

```
1min 33.326s sendmail.service
     58.872s podman-auto-update.service
     40.822s mpd.service
     33.722s systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
     29.988s user@1000.service
     26.474s apache2.service
     26.234s lightdm.service
     26.217s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     25.138s vmware.service
     24.550s networkd-dispatcher.service
     23.020s udisks2.service
     22.879s accounts-daemon.service
     15.663s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     14.961s avahi-daemon.service
     14.959s NetworkManager.service
     14.594s polkit.service
     14.592s power-profiles-daemon.service
     14.210s switcheroo-control.service
     14.203s wpa_supplicant.service
```

UPDATE after disabling sendmail.service

```
55.560s podman-auto-update.service
42.642s mpd.service
33.696s systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
30.868s user@1000.service
26.124s apache2.service
25.182s networkd-dispatcher.service
25.012s udisks2.service
23.658s lightdm.service
23.642s plymouth-quit-wait.service
22.550s vmware.service
22.424s accounts-daemon.service
16.712s systemd-journal-flush.service
16.003s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
15.687s systemd-udev-settle.service
15.422s avahi-daemon.service
15.420s NetworkManager.service
15.031s polkit.service
15.018s power-profiles-daemon.service
14.880s vmware-USBArbitrator.service
14.623s switcheroo-control.service
14.618s wpa_supplicant.service
14.145s winbind.service
14.015s lxc-net.service
13.885s systemd-logind.service
13.360s dev-sda2.device
10.786s ModemManager.service
10.315s smartmontools.service
10.246s gpu-manager.service
 9.491s systemd-networkd.service
 8.443s timidity.service
 8.324s smbd.service
 8.098s nmbd.service
 7.389s cups.service
 7.121s pwrstatd.service
 7.099s packagekit.service
 6.850s lxc.service
 5.758s rsyslog.service
 4.943s systemd-udevd.service
 4.324s systemd-modules-load.service
 4.090s gpm.service
 3.690s e2scrub_reap.service
```

UPDATE: Most worried journal entries as it asked

```
Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8

r8169 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control

Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001828-0x000000000000182F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001800-0x000000000000187F (\>

Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich

Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc kernel: sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through


Apr 16 01:50:19 eliasc systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/plymouth-start.service:16: Unit configured to use KillMode=none. This is unsafe, as it disables systemd's p>
Apr 16 01:50:20 eliasc kernel: ashmem_linux: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.

Apr 16 01:50:22 eliasc systemd-modules-load[406]: Failed to find module 'dhd'

Apr 16 01:50:24 eliasc systemd-udevd[425]: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-anbox-modules-dkms.rules:1 NAME="%k" is ignored, as it breaks kernel supplied names.

Apr 16 01:50:27 eliasc kernel: at24 0-0052: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator

Apr 16 01:50:28 eliasc kernel: scsi 11:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 8
Apr 16 01:50:28 eliasc kernel: scsi 11:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
Apr 16 01:50:28 eliasc kernel: scsi 11:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19

Apr 16 01:50:30 eliasc kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: dmic_detect option is deprecated, pass snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 option instead
Apr 16 01:50:30 eliasc kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: dmic_detect option is deprecated, pass snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 option instead

Apr 16 01:50:42 eliasc smartd[750]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], no ATA CHECK POWER STATUS support, ignoring -n Directive

Apr 16 01:51:11 eliasc kernel: vmmon: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.

Configuration file /etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.discover.notifier.desktop is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.

Apr 16 01:51:37 eliasc systemd-xdg-autostart-generator[1373]: Not generating service for XDG autostart app-unity\x2dsettings\x2ddaemon-autostart.service, error parsing Exec= line: No such file or directory

Apr 16 01:51:42 eliasc systemd[1518]: mpd.socket: Failed to create listening socket ([::]:6600): Address already in use
Apr 16 01:51:42 eliasc systemd[1322]: mpd.socket: Failed to receive listening socket ([::]:6600): Input/output error
Apr 16 01:51:42 eliasc systemd[1322]: mpd.socket: Failed to listen on sockets: Input/output error
Apr 16 01:51:42 eliasc systemd[1322]: mpd.socket: Failed with result 'resources'.
Apr 16 01:51:42 eliasc systemd[1322]: Failed to listen on mpd.socket.

Apr 16 01:51:43 eliasc sm-mta[1533]: My unqualified host name (eliasc) unknown; sleeping for retry
Apr 16 01:51:44 eliasc sm-msp-queue[1549]: My unqualified host name (eliasc) unknown; sleeping for retry
Apr 16 01:51:46 eliasc systemd[1087]: mpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 16 01:51:46 eliasc systemd[1087]: mpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 16 01:51:46 eliasc systemd[1087]: Failed to start Music Player Daemon.
Apr 16 01:51:46 eliasc systemd[1322]: mpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 16 01:51:46 eliasc systemd[1322]: mpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire-media-session[1538]: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire-media-session[1538]: could not set nice-level to -11: Permission denied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire[1537]: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire[1537]: could not set nice-level to -11: Permission denied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire-media-session[1522]: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire-media-session[1522]: could not set nice-level to -11: Permission denied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire[1521]: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire[1521]: could not set nice-level to -11: Permission denied

Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire-media-session[1538]: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire-media-session[1538]: could not make thread realtime: Permission denied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire[1537]: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire[1537]: could not make thread realtime: Permission denied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire-media-session[1522]: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire-media-session[1522]: could not make thread realtime: Permission denied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire[1521]: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pipewire[1521]: could not make thread realtime: Permission denied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pulseaudio[1523]: Home directory not accessible: Permission denied

Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc pulseaudio[1578]: Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc systemd[1322]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc systemd[1322]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 16 01:51:47 eliasc systemd[1322]: Failed to start Sound Service
Apr 16 01:51:56 eliasc pulseaudio[1539]: Sink output does not exist.
Apr 16 01:51:56 eliasc pulseaudio[1539]: Source input does not exist.

Apr 16 01:52:43 eliasc sm-mta[1533]: unable to qualify my own domain name (eliasc) -- using short name
Apr 16 01:52:44 eliasc sm-msp-queue[1549]: unable to qualify my own domain name (eliasc) -- using short name

Apr 16 01:52:58 eliasc org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper[2031]: org.kde.powerdevil: no kernel backlight interface found

Apr 16 08:32:10 eliasc systemd[1087]: plasma-baloorunner.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 16 08:32:10 eliasc systemd[1087]: Failed to start KRunner provider for baloo file indexer.
```

Comment: This could be down to malfunctioning DNS resolution or/and the fact that your disks are connected via USB. The latter is a very bad idea specially if it's a USB2 connection.

Comment: RE: Postgresql versions - Debian allows multiple versions of Pg to be installed (and even running, on different ports) simultaneously.  While you can run like that indefinitely, the main reason is to provide a safe upgrade process. You're supposed to follow the semi-automated upgrade process when a major new version of pg is installed (at a time that suits you), and that requires both the old  and the new pg to be installed.  Once you've migrated your databases from the old version to the new, you can remove the old version.  See `/usr/share/doc/postgresql-common/README.Debian.gz`

Comment: You have Pg 10, 12, and 13 installed and running.  You should check which, if any, you've been using to store data. If 10 or 12 have any data, migrate it to Pg 13, then uninstall 10 and 12.   My guess is that only Pg 10 is likely to be in active use and have any data in it, because that's probably what you installed first and you've just allowed the `postgresql`, `postgresql-client`, and `postgresql-common` packages to be upgraded without paying attention.

Comment: about postsqrl, i have uninstalled it. i had the idea that is needed for sqlite. but sqlite opens my databases perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend foregoing the `systemd-analyze` and instead looking at the booting steps in more detail with `sudo journalctl -b`. This command will also color-code lines based on their significance (red for errors etc.)

Also, with `journalctl` you will be able to analyze multiple previous boots, all listed with `sudo journalctl --list-boots` and access their logs using:

```
journalctl -b [ID]

    [ID]                -1 for previous boot, -2 for two boots back etc.
```

---

As far as the `sendmail.service`, the likely reason is that it is failing to resolve your hostname until timing out and going to sleep allowing the boot to continue.  This will be reported in the `journalctl -b` logs and might look as follows:

```
sendmail[1740]: My unqualified host name ([hostname]) unknown; sleeping for retry
sendmail[1740]: unable to qualify my own domain name ([hostname]) -- using short name
```

If you check the following location

```
ls -alh /var/lib/sendmail
```

you might likely find a file similar to this one:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 root smmsp 11M Apr 16 02:01 /var/lib/sendmail/dead.letter
```

and if you look inside `/var/log/` you will find `mail.log` and `mail.err`

and I can almost guarantee that your `mail.log` file will be huge, but with a sequence of 3 lines repeating over and over looking like so:

```
Apr 12 16:01:04 [usr] sm-msp-queue[64338]: 23CK11C9064338: to=postmaster, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=32831, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
Apr 12 16:01:04 [user] sm-msp-queue[64338]: 233NL1Ph021284: to=[user], delay=8+20:40:02, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=121459, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
Apr 12 16:01:04 [user] sm-msp-queue[64338]: 233NL1Ph021284: 23CK11CA064338: return to sender: Cannot send message for 5 days
```

**Given that you aren't sure what `sendmail` is or why its running, and seeing how `sendmail.service` is giving you nothing but issues, it is safe to assume you are not actively using it. In that case I would recommend disabling it, which you can do so using:**

```
sudo systemctl disable sendmail
```

reboot and then analyze your timing and let us know if the 1m40s delay is no longer there.

Comment: sendmail.service i found out that is used when you set localhost email services with smtp protocol?  Thunderbird over internet do not used that service. right? i disabled it.

Comment: All these entries repeating itself many times. I think is the reason that music services is taking such long time to set up at boot. cause they fail.... I have tried a lot of solutions without luck. Most annoying entries are these ones `Failed to find module 'dhd'  Failed to listen on mpd.socket. Sink output does not exist.  Source input does not exist.`

Comment: i read about "dhd". `Compile wifi driver from Broadcom and get a  .ko file(such as dhd.ko).` I have no wifi in desktop. i can remove it? how if not found?

Comment: solution d=for mpd maybe the solution is `https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=120371` rebooting and i will post

Comment: New info `Startup finished in 35.848s (firmware) + 9.398s (loader) + 11.659s (kernel) + 1min 58.973s (userspace) = 2min 55.878s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 58.933s in userspace`

Comment: though ... mpd could not initiated so sound problems persist....

Comment: Ok, I think may have an idea regarding the mpd service(as well as the podman-auto-update.service). First, lets's run a test by disabling `mpd` with `sudo systemctl disable mpd.service' and restarting and see if the corresponding time delay, then once the system boots up and you have a shell first try: `ping google.com` to make sure you have a working DNS resolver,then `sudo systemctl enable mpd.service; sudo systemctl start mpd.service`.If it hangs or fails while starting, open another terminal window and run `sudo journalctl -r` and look at the lines corresponding to `mpd.service` for info